# What software can i use to make hand drawn visuals for Word/Powerpoint?

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing

What software can I use for creating handwritten notes/visuals/graphs to put into Word or Powerpoint docs?  I don't want to use live trace in Illustrator because I don't think I need something so complex.

Are there any easy solutions? I have a Mac if that makes a difference.

[image]

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, user71753. Can you tell us something about your efforts? Your example doesn't seem to be generated by a software.  Have you tried to replicate the effect e.g. by acquiring (with a scanner or a camera) a text handwritten on a paper? Have you tried to use a smartphone app to draw such elements and export them on your mac? Have you tried to connect to your mac a graphic tablet?

Comment: Do you have access to Illustrator? Because that would pretty much be the application I would recommend, if I were to recommend any... Scanner and automatic vector conversion seems like the simpler way to me.

Comment: Hi Paolo and Joonas.  Thanks for both your replies.  I dont have illustrator at the moment.  I am not very good on it (was on a work computer), so I wondered if there was a simpler process.  I did try photographing and just editing in preview, I havent tried smartphone app or graphic tablet - illustrator may actually be the fastest solution for me..

Comment: Did you consider doing this directly in powerpoint? I mean if your computer has an attached stylus then it should be quite straightforward. Now the real question is is your hand as neat as that, there are some really neat handwriting fonts that fool the same style by having multiples of same character, this may be simpler on you.

Answer (score 2):

The graphic you posted could be done using a mouse (or, likely a [Wacom](http://www.wacom.com/en-us)) into a full on graphic editor, like Illustrator or Photoshop but it also could have been done much more cheaply on a phone or tablet and a stylus (or even a finger)! Even the free iOS Notes app can scribble text, though it's not as good as some of the ones you could find in the store. One of my favorites is [Paper by 53](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id506003812?mt=8).

In fact, I just created the following graphic on my iPhone using [Paper](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id506003812?mt=8) and my finger in seconds (would have looked better with a stylus and more time/effort :).

[image]

Comment: Hi Rgthree.  Many thanks for the above.  That was pretty much what I was after.  You have saved me heaps of time (and money) - many thanks!